# show app name in heroku console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, irb

If I run a console on heroku, it looks like this:

```
heroku run console --app myapp-production
irb(main):001:0>
```

This seems a whole lot more dangerous than something like this:

```
heroku run console --app myapp-production
myapp-production:001:0>
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

@Peter,

You need to create a plugin as this: https://github.com/hone/heroku_colorize_console

And after run this `heroku plugins:install <your_git_repo>`.

Based on the example above this appeared very simple to implement.